# Does anyone have a good pattern for initializing a spring bean once another one has been initialized?

Tags: java, spring, lazy-initialization

I've got a situation that keeps cropping up in my system and I'm looking for a good code/config pattern.  I haven't come up with one that makes me happy yet.

The system is spring-based and almost all of the beans are lazily-initialized.  There are a number of different main classes that use the same spring context.  Each one ends up using a different subset of the beans by explicitly initializing a few beans and then spring takes care of initializing all the dependencies. Everything works great except for this one case.

The problem is that some of my beans use a pattern (in the spring config) where my business bean is declared and then another bean depends on it and provides some peripheral functionality.  However, the natural dependency of other beans is the former, being the business class.

Here's an example:

```xml
<bean id="cache">
  ...
</bean>

<bean id="cacheCuller" class="ScheduledJobBean">
  <property name="scheduler" ref="scheduler"/>
  <property name="jobDetail">
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
      <property name="targetObject" ref="cache"/>
      <property name="targetMethod" value="removeExpiredEntries"/>
      <property name="concurrent" value="false"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="repeatInterval" value="300000" />
</bean>
```

So, the second bean above basically registers a trigger with the scheduler that will cause a method on the first bean to be called periodically.  Remember, all these beans are lazy.  I don't want to create "cacheCuller" and have that initialize "cache" if there are no active "cache" client beans.  I want spring to initialize "cache" when it needs to be injected into a dependency (this is easy) but I also want it to initialize "cacheCuller" immediately afterwards (this is hard).

I know that I can put the scheduling logic into the "cache" class, but I thought it would be nice to keep it in spring configuration.  I'd also like to keep the "cache" class free of spring-specific code.  If other beans naturally depended on "cacheCuller" this would be easy, but they don't.

The same situation comes up in other areas, like registering the beans with the MBeanServer.  I'd like to have a second bean register the business bean, but I don't want that to initialize the business bean itself if it's not being used as a dependency of some other (third) bean.

Comment: Just curious, what benefit do you get from having all of your beans initialized lazily?

Comment: It makes it so that spring only starts exactly what needs to be started for whatever I'm doing.  I don't have to worry about extraneous thread pools, et cetera.  This allows me to have multiple main() methods that initialize some beans and everything that's needed it automatically determined and started.  If I want to combine multiple of my logical processes, all I have to do is change the "root" beans that they need and they just work.  The list of beans can be set at runtime as well.  It doesn't have to be hardcoded or prepared ahead of time.

Comment: I should also add that I tend to use the scala REPL for interactive testing and this works beautifully with the lazy setup.  I can ask for whatever bean I want (without having to plan for a subset for it ahead of time) and make interactive method calls on it without having to think about it.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for [depends-on](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-dependson).

Comment: That's actually the opposite of what I'm looking for.  depends-on will make sure that one bean has been initialized before initializing another.  I want to initialize bean A immediately _after_ bean B is initialized but _only if_ bean B is actually ever initialized.

Comment: Why is the before vs. after so important?

Comment: Because the bean that I'm saying needs to be initialized after the first one _depends_ on the first one.  So, it can't be initialized first.

Answer (score 0):

> There are a number of different main classes that use the same spring context. Each one ends up using a different subset of the beans by explicitly initializing a few beans and then spring takes care of initializing all the dependencies.

Maybe you should re-consider this approach.

You could split up the application context into several files, and have each main classes load the required combination thereof. That will make your application context more modular and easier to understand IMHO (e.g. eliminate the problem you've described).

Comment: I see your point, but the thing that I like about the current design is that spring figures out what needs to be initialized.  If I break the context up into multiple files (without lazy instantiation - I assume that's what you're talking about), then it becomes a manual process of partitioning the beans and figuring out what needs to be initialized where.

Comment: "The thing that I like about the current design is that spring figures out what needs to be initialized." -- No offense, but this sounds as if  you like the part that doesn't work for you. If the best thing about it doesn't work, then maybe you really should re-consider your approach.